# Using outbound Node-RED email to local SMTP server

Tags: smtp, node-red

I have a local SMTP email server I use for testing purposes running on my machine.  It listens for SMTP on port 25.  I am able to send and receive emails to it using a regular email client.

When I build a Node-RED flow that contains an e-mail output node and configure its properties with:

`to: <email address>
server: localhost
port: 25`

and submit a flow, I get the error:

`25 Feb 16:43:24 - [error] [e-mail:<email address>] Error: 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:`

I am at a loss on how to proceed.   Looking at the messages, it almost appears that there is some form of SSL negotiation/test at play here.  Switching on trace on my SMTP server, I find the following logs each time I try and run a flow:

`"TCPIP" 10708   "2016-02-25 16:43:08.294"   "TCP - 127.0.0.1 connected to 127.0.0.1:25."
"DEBUG" 10708   "2016-02-25 16:43:08.298"   "Creating session 22"
"SMTPD" 10708   22  "2016-02-25 16:43:08.298"   "127.0.0.1" "SENT: 220 WIN7-X64 ESMTP"
"DEBUG" 9772    "2016-02-25 16:43:08.299"   "Ending session 22"`

It appears that the Node-RED node is sending a connection request, getting back the SMTP `220` response and then failing immediately after that.

Comment: Did you set a username and password?

Comment: Yes ... I tried a bunch of permutations ... with password and without password.  All seem to show the same characteristics.  From the EMail server perspective, all we ever see is what is posted above ... a connect request from the outbbound email node, the SMTP server sending back its "220" message and then the error logged in both debug and to the Node-RED console.  The actual email server I am using is the "hmailserver" that is freely downloadable.  I use that for all my PoCs and my confidence is high in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see Dave has replied to the github [issue](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/issues/180) but just to close the loop on this question.

At this time (Feb 2016) the node assumes SSL is always available and enabled, at some point we need to go back to the email node and find a simple way to expose a lot more of the nodemailer options to allow connections to a wider range of email providers both public and private.

Comment: Thank you sir ... for future readers:

The answer to the question is:

currently (Feb 2016) - The email output node requires that the SMTP server be connected to by SSL.  In my failing tests, I had been connecting over plain TCP at port 25 as opposed to attempting to configure my email server with SSL at a different port.

Comment: As a post-script, I created a self signed certificate for my EMail server and configured my server to use it.  Now when I attempt to send an email from Node-RED to my email server I get a new error:

`26 Feb 22:34:32 - [error] [e-mail:kolban@test,com] Error: self signed certificate`

it looks like we don't support self signed certificates either.

Comment: If you set this environment variable before starting Node-RED it should accept (all) self signed certs `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Comment: Excellent the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` worked perfectly.  Thank you for that.  By googling, it seems that this variable is a "hack" (my words) / "override" for the property "rejectUnauthorized" on the HTTPS package.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and have a nasty hack that will enable mail to go via my local exchange server's plain SMTP, with no auth.

Edit the .../61-email.js file and change it thusly:

```
   var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: node.outserver,
        port: node.outport,
        secure: false,
        ignoreTLS: true //,
    //    auth: {
    //        user: node.userid,
    //        pass: node.password
    //    }
    });
```

Comment: Since the nodes are open source, I suspect what we might want to do is create an issue, flag the issue as being worked upon, make the proper changes to the nodes (including parameterization and doc updates) and then issue GitHub pull requests to have our changes merged back into the core/base.

Comment: Yes, I will be doing that, I'll also make it integrated into the node itself, so it's an option fro within node red. I just though I'd share what I'd done.